# Copy Constructor Being Called on the Wrong Object

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm currently implementing a copy constructor for a Linked List class. When I create a new instance of the class with another Linked List as a parameter, the constructor is being called for the object I'm passing as the parameter. This is leaving me confused beyond belief. Here is the section necessary to understand what's going on in the main method:

```
int main()
{
   LinkedList ll;
   LinkedList ll2(ll);
}
```

So, instead of calling the copy constructor for ll2, the copy constructor for ll is being called. I've confirmed that the size of ll is correctly 3 before I attempt to copy ll into a new LinkedList, namely ll2. After the copy though, both have the same size, greater than 3, but even more weird, the copy constructor of ll is being called, not that of ll2. Since I'm using VC++, I've stepped through the program to confirm this.

Here is the copy constructor for the LinkedList class:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList & other)        
{
   LLNode *otherCurNode = other.GetFirst();
   if (otherCurNode != NULL)
   {
      front = new LLNode(otherCurNode->GetValue(), NULL, NULL);
      back = front;
   }
   else
   {
      front = NULL;
      back = NULL;
   }
   LLNode *curNode = front;
   while (otherCurNode != NULL)
   {
      Insert(otherCurNode->GetValue(), curNode);
      curNode = curNode->GetNext();
      otherCurNode = otherCurNode->GetNext();
      back = curNode;
   }
   numNodes = other.GetSize();
}
```

My apologies if this ends up being a simple problem - I'm fairly new to C++. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From the code you showed, the first line should call a copy ctor for `ll`, the second for `ll2`. How do you determine which copy ctor is called? Can you reduce your code to a simple, self-contained snippet that exhibits the behavior you think you#re seeing? Very likely, in boiling down (a copy of) your code to such a snippet, you'll find your problem. If not, you have a perfect piece of code to come back here and ask (a new question) about.

Comment: WOW. I was following your advice and slowly adding pieces to a very basic program to replicate the functionality. Then, I came back to work on my program again and Voila, the problem was gone. I have zero idea as to what I did since I don't recall modifying any of the code for at least an hour, but I'm going to undo some of the most recent changes to see if I can't figure out what was causing it...

Comment: So I've discovered what the problem was. My structure is as follows: LinkedList.h contains the class declaration, LinkedList.cpp contains the implementation for all of the methods contained within the class. TestCases.cpp includes LinkedList.h. BUT, I was declaring my class variables for LinkedList within LinkedList.cpp, not my header file. I can promise you all that after three solid hours of looking at this, I won't be making this mistake again. Thank you all again for all your answers! Your answers helped me get steam to figure it all out =)

Comment: I wish I could mark both John and Alex's answers as correct as they led me in the right direction for my problem... =(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
LinkedList ll = LinkedList();
```

This creates a linked list instance, and this instance is then copy constructed. This looks like a Java or C#-ism. It is actually equivalent to:

```
LinkedList ll(LinkedList());
```

To create an empty linked list, simply write:

```
LinkedList ll;
```

This will implicitly call the default constructor.

Also, make sure that you do have a default constructor which properly initializes the linked list to empty. If you don't have one then the list's variables will end up with whatever garbage values are on the stack.

Comment: I guess that's my Java/VB/C# shining through =). I fixed my original code but the problem is still present.

Comment: No, do not add parentheses to call the constructor explicitly.  For constructors that take no arguments, it will be interpreted as a function declaration.

Comment: @jamesdlin Good point. I was about to add a note about the `typename` keyword but really it's better I just remove that sentence entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Weird things are often a sign of improper memory handling. I can see one immediate problem with the code you posted and there may be similar problems in other functions.

On the line `while (otherCurNode->GetNext() != NULL)`, bad things will happen if `otherCurNode` is already `NULL`. This is the case both when the other list is empty as well as when you reach the end of the list via `otherCurNode = otherCurNode->GetNext();`. You really want to make it `while (otherCurNode != NULL)`.

Comment: Understandable. I recognize that this is a problem, but really doesn't address the real problem at hand in that the constructor for the wrong object is being called. Thanks for the tip though =)

Answer (score 1):

> So, instead of calling the copy constructor for ll2, the copy constructor for ll is being called, and ll2 is being set to the same reference as ll.

You can make sure this is not what happening. Your `ll` and `ll2` variables (BTW you can see why using lowercase `l` in short names is never a good idea) are allocated on the stack, they are not references. To see this, open Quick Watch while both variables are in scope, and type `&ll`, and then `&ll2`. You will see they have different addresses.

What do your default constructor and assignment operator look like? Are there any other constructors? Any other places where you assign `front` instance variable?

Comment: indeed, I've checked and ensured that ll and ll2 are located in different location in memory. What is interesting though, is that front for both values points to that same location in memory...

The location of front for ll is modified during the line LinkedList ll2(ll); This whole situation is leaving me baffled.

Comment: Looks like you have left your assignment operator to be the default, which is automatically generated by the compiler. It assigns all members, including `front`. This is not the behavior you want.

Comment: The rule is, if you implement custom copy constructor, implement the assignment operator as well.

Comment: Could this really be an issue? The empty constructor simple sets front and back to null and sets numNodes to 0. That's it. As you may have noticed, the same problem is arising if I simply create ll, then call the copy constructor to ll2. No other funny business. front and back are pointers, so the assignment operator should never be used...or am I mistaken? Also, I have implemented the assignment operator already.

Comment: Are you sure your assignment operator does not copy `front` as a pointer and makes a deep copy instead? As a side question, how do you handle code duplication between copy constructor and the assignment?

Comment: One more thing... once an object is constructed, you cannot call a copy constructor for it. One constructor per instance. That probably explains why assignment operator gets into play. Can I see the method signature you are using when implementing it?